# What is the remainder of dividing $14^{256}$ by $17$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

> What is the remainder of dividing $14^{256}$ by $17$?

$$14^2\equiv 196\equiv 9 \pmod{17}\\14^{4}\equiv81\equiv13\pmod{17}\\14^8\equiv169\equiv16\pmod{17}\\14^{16}\equiv256\equiv1\pmod{17}\\14^{256}\equiv1^{16}\equiv1\pmod{17}$$

Soon rest is $1$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. $a^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$ for all $a$ not divisible by $17$, so also $a^{16\cdot k}$.

Comment: Tank you @DanielFischer!!!

Comment: @marcelolpjunior Your ans. is absolutely wright.

Comment: $$14\equiv -3 \pmod{17}$$ makes the first line computation easier ;)

Comment: Learning about  [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) might help  you

Answer (score 4):

Since gcd$(14,17)=1$

Using Euler's Formula,

$$14^{\phi(17)}\equiv1\pmod{17}$$

$$14^{16}\equiv1\pmod{17}$$

but $16^2$ is $256$,

$$14^{256}\equiv1\pmod{17}$$

Comment: I have not had the good fortune to study this formula, soon, I hope!

Comment: @marcelolpjunior Are u know the Fermat's theorem?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior You can use Fermat's theorem the statement is if gcd$(a,p)=1$ then $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct. You could also use [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), which states that, if $p$ is a prime, then
$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
where $a$ is not a multiple of $p$. In your case, $a=14$ and $p=17$. Hence, we obtain $$14^{17-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \implies 14^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$$
Now we have
$$14^{256} = (14^{16})^{16} \equiv 1^{16} \pmod{17} \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$$

Comment: Truth ... INCREDIBLE ...$$(14,17)=1\\14^{16}\equiv1\pmod{17}\\(14^{16})^{16}=14^{256}\equiv1^{16}\equiv1\pmod{17}$$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: $\;14=-3\pmod{17}\;$ , and $\,(-3)^4=3^4=13=-4\pmod{17}\;$ , so doing arithmetic modulo $\,17\,$ all through:

$$14^{256}=(-3)^{256}=\left((-3)^4\right)^{64}=(-4)^{64}=4^{64}$$

but then $\;4^2=-1\pmod {17}\;$ , so...